# Получить из массива только одно значение

Tags: php, twig

У меня есть массивы:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["property_id"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["property"]=>
    string(11) "Weight Loss"
    ["category"]=>
    string(15) "Health benefits"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["property_id"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["property"]=>
    string(12) "Heart health"
    ["category"]=>
    string(15) "Health benefits"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["property_id"]=>
    string(2) "13"
    ["property"]=>
    string(15) "Prevents cancer"
    ["category"]=>
    string(15) "Health benefits"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["property_id"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["property"]=>
    string(8) "Eye care"
    ["category"]=>
    string(15) "Health benefits"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["property_id"]=>
    string(2) "23"
    ["property"]=>
    string(11) "New Product"
    ["category"]=>
    string(14) "Promo Homepage"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["property_id"]=>
    string(2) "25"
    ["property"]=>
    string(9) "Promotion"
    ["category"]=>
    string(14) "Promo Homepage"
  }
}
```

Из этих массивов в шаблоне мне нужно вывести поле `property.category`только один раз, но из-за вхождение в цикл `for` у меня вывелось:

```
Health benefits
Weight Loss
Health benefits
Heart health
Health benefits
Prevents cancer
Health benefits
Eye care
```

Вывод в твиге:

```
{% for key, property in product.properties %}
     {% if property.category == 'Health benefits' %}
     <h4 style="width: 100%; font-weight: bold">{{ property.category }}</h4>
     <span class="property">{{ property.property }}</span>
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Как мне вывести Health benefits, в цикле  только один раз, без повторения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм, вывести заголовок по `loop.first`?
Используйте [документацию](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html)!

```
{% for key, property in product.properties %}
     {% if property.category == 'Health benefits' %}
       {% if loop.first %}
         <h4 style="width: 100%; font-weight: bold">{{ property.category }}</h4>
       {% endif %}
     <span class="property">{{ property.property }}</span>
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```